# NCrunch doesn't recognise environment variable

Tags: .net, visual-studio, environment-variables, ncrunch

I've set my `NCrunch cache storage path` to `%TEMP%\NCrunchCache`. However, I get the following error:

```
NCrunch was unable to access the directory 
'C:\src\solutionFolder\%TEMP%\NCrunchCache' as specified in the configuration for this solution.
Cache data will instead be stored in the default location
```

The [documentation](https://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_solution-configuration_ncrunch-cache-storage-path) suggests this is possible:

> From NCrunch v2.20, this setting supports specifying environment variables (i.e. '%MyCacheRootDir%\MySolution')

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting VS since changing the environment variable? When you start a process, it gets copies of the environment variables, so if VS was opened before you changed it, you might be working with old variables.

I'd consider closing all VS instances, then making sure you don't have any `NCrunch.BuildHostXXX.x86.exe` processes in Task Manager.

Comment: While this looked promising, it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Restarting does not work. Using `%AppData%\NCrunchCache` still leads to `C:\src\Solution\%AppData%\NCrunchCache` (using v3.6)